# Angular 11: How to access a native element inside ng-template

Tags: angular, typescript

I have problem to access element inside `<ng-template>`. It return `undefined`.

This my demo code.

**HTML:**

```
<ng-template #enabled>
   <div class="form-group">
      <div class="ml-4">
         <input type="checkbox" id="verifyDetail" #validate class="form-check-input" [(ngModel)]="checkStatus"
         [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
         (click)="detailformSubmission(detailForm.valid, $event)"  (blur)="detailformSubmission(detailForm.valid, $event)">
      </div>
   </div>
</ng-template>
```

**ts:**

```
@ViewChild('validate', {static: true}) vrt!: ElementRef<any>;

ngOnInit(){
console.log(this.vrt);
}
```

`console.log` returns `undefined`.

Comment: Its also undefined in ngAfterViewInit?

Comment: yes.. it also undefined in `ngAfterViewInit`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could remove `{ static: true}` from `@ViewChild` decorator (default is `false`). After that you could implement `AfterViewInit` interface and use `ngAfterViewInit` lifecylce method in which you should be able to access reference from your template `.html` file.

Comment: I cannot use <ng-container> because I use ngIf else like this <ng-component *ngIf="(checkStatus == false && detailForm.valid == false) || page == 2 ; then disabled; else enabled">                   </ng-component>

Comment: Will edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `<ng-container>` instead of `<ng-template>`.

Comment: He can use template tag if it follows up from a container before with a ngIf else.

Comment: Yes but that's not the case now.

Comment: I cannot use `<ng-container>` because I use ngIf else like this `<ng-component *ngIf="(checkStatus == false && detailForm.valid == false) || page == 2 ; then disabled; else enabled">
                  </ng-component>`

Comment: You are wrong. You can use it.